# A function between its left derivative and right derivative.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $ f $ be a function defined on $ \mathbb{R} $. Assume that the left and right derivatives exist and denoted as $ f_{-}'(x) $ and $ f_{+}'(x) $. If $ f $ is between $ f_{-}'(x) $ and $ f_{+}'(x) $, then $ f $ is a increasing funcition.

For the statement above, I do not know whether it is right or not, can you give me some references or hints?

Comment: Maybe a more interesting case it's when $f'_-(x) \neq f'_+(x)$ for some $x$

Comment: Intuitively I think that no such function on $\mathbb{R}$ could exist though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f(x)= -e^x$, this is a *decreasing* function with $f'_-(x) = f_{+}'(x) = f(x)$.